# Android disable landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, mode

I wish to disable the landscape view in an android application . I've used :

```
 <activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

It works but there is a slightly big problem . If I rotate the screen the activity restarts , and when it comes back , the screen is still in portrait mode .  I want my app to completely ignore the device's position . There is no point in disabling the landscape view if when I rotate the device the activity restarts ( the screen becomes black for a few seconds , and then the activity appears again still in portrait mode ) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

Comment: in manifest , right ? I insterted that line in each one of my activities and when I rotate the device the activities are still restarting.

Comment: it works for me , try this then android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"

Comment: yeah that was it `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"`

Answer (score 0):

write a class and extend it to the activity. In that class add this code to a method.
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
Then call this method to the activites to which you want to disable the landscape mode..