# How to disable rotating to landscape mode?

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685179/2255924). Could not find **configChanges** in manifest file. Anyways, how to disable rotation of screen(to landscape mode)?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joericharduz.akita"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.joericharduz.akita.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: configChanges is under the activity tag try it will work

Comment: @kalyanpvs maybe I should add it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just as kalyanpvs has said, the `configChanges` are under `activity`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.neundorfer.microraphandheld.v1.ParentActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 10):

Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your Manifest. Easiest way to do it (inside your Activity tags).

Comment: that attribute is not available under the `<application>` tag.

Comment: @TronicZomB Ah, didn't think it was but thought I'd throw it out there just in case. I'll edit :)